# A Maximal Monotone Operator on $H^1_0(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, sobolev-spaces, monotone-operator-theory

I am trying to figure out if the operator

$$
\langle N(u), v \rangle_{\mathcal{H}^*, \mathcal{H}}=\int \limits_0^1 u'(x)u(x)v(x)dx
$$ is maximal monotone on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}=H^1_0(0,1)$, i.e. if

$$
\langle N(u)-N(v), u-v \rangle_{\mathcal{H}^*, \mathcal{H}}\geq 0
$$ for all $u,v\in \mathcal{H}.$

I already found the identity using integration by parts

$$
\langle N(u), u \rangle_{\mathcal{H}^*, \mathcal{H}}=\int \limits_0^1 u^2(x)\cdot u'(x)dx=0
$$ but I simply can't figure out the rest.

I´m starting to think, that it is not true, but couldn't find a counter example.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that the inequality you wrote defines monotonicity, not maximal monotonicity.

Comment: You are right. The assumption I need to verify, is that the set-valued operator $N:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \rightarrow \mathcal{H}^*$ is maximal monotone. In this case $N$ is single valued, so maximal monotone should be equivalent to monotone, right?

Comment: No, the signum function is monotone (regardless of how you define it at zero) but not maximal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write (integration by parts, Taylor expansion):
$$
\langle N(u)-N(v),u-v\rangle   = \int_0^1 (u'u - v'v)(u-v) dx
= \int_0^1 (u-v)\frac12\frac d{dx}(u^2-v^2) dx\\
= -\frac12\int_0^1 (u'-v')(u^2-v^2) dx\\
= -\frac12\int_0^1 (u'-v')(2v(u-v) + (u-v)^2) dx\\
=-\frac12\int_0^1 v\frac d{dx}(u-v)^2 + \frac13\frac d{dx}(u-v)^3\ dx\\
=\frac12\int_0^1 v'(u-v)^2.
$$
Define $v(x) := \min(x, 1-x) \in H^1_0(0,1)$ with $v'=-1$ on $(1/2,1)$.
Now choose $u$ such that $u(x)=v(x)$ on $(0,1/2)$ and $u(x)\ne v(x)$ on $(1/2,1)$. Then $\langle N(u)-N(v),u-v\rangle<0$.

Hence $N$ is not monotone.

Note that $\langle N(u),u\rangle=0$, hence the choices $u=0$ or $v=0$ do not prove non-monotonicity.

Comment: I´m not sure about the very first equation? How does it equal to
$$
\langle N(u)-N(v), u-v\rangle =\int u^2u'-uu'v-vv'u+v^2v'dx?
$$

Comment: ups, misread the definition of the operator.

Comment: Tried to correct it. Please check again..